# How to add(sum) the first element to next n elements till the first element becomes zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add(sum) the first element to next n elements till the first element becomes zero?

Example:

Input:

```
6 7 1 3 6
10
```

first element -> 6

a= first element =6

next element to 6 is -> 7 -> 7+3 (adding three because  the element not need to exceed X)

a=6-3=3

need to add 3 to next element.

next element to 7 is 1 -> 1+3=4

a=3-3=0 (a(first element) becomes zero)

so i need to stop the loop

needed output

```
0 10 4 2 6
```

I tried but my code not adding the remaining to next value.Is my logic is correct?.What mistake i made??

My code:

```
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
c=int(input())
ans=[]
for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
  a=l[0]
  l[i]+=a-(l[i]+a)%c 
  a-=(l[i]+a)%c 
  if l[i]==c:
    i+=1
  if a<=0:
    break
  
print(l)
```

Output i got

```
[6, 10, 1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not very clear. This looks like a coding challenge type question, so maybe you could link to or reproduce the question as originally worded?

Comment: Hello @Stuart this is not a coding question and this is not a full question I just added the part of logic I used and I didn't expecting full code just algorithm to achieve my mentioned output

Comment: I don't understand the statement "three because the element not need to exceed X"  how was 3 selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works for your example:

```py
numbers = [6, 7, 1, 3, 6]
total = 10
i = 1
while i < len(numbers) and numbers[0] != 0:
    shift = min(total - numbers[i], numbers[0])
    numbers[i] += shift
    numbers[0] -= shift
    i += 1

print(numbers)
```

Careful, if the total you need is smaller than numbers[i] for exemple, it will reduce numbers[i] and numbers[0] will grow.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has a few issue.
You use (l[i]+a)%c twice, but the value of l[i] change inbetween.
Also, you never change the value of l[0] (you only use the variable a) so it stays at 6.
Here is some code I wrote with a simpler apporach:

```
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
c=int(input())

ans=[]
for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
  
    x = c-l[i]    
    if x < l[0]:
        l[i] += x
        l[0] -= x
    else:
        l[i] += l[0]
        l[0] = 0
        break
  
print(l)
```

You add from l[0] while you still have enough to add, if not you add what remains and end the loop.